# Setting up a Range in txt file with linux commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, centos

i have a file containing number ranges

ex.:

```
12345 00/99
123456 20/80
```

and i want to translate them into 1234500 and write every number up to 1234599 automatically.

is there a way of doing this with shell?

Comment: Tell us where you got and what problems did you face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne 'if (m{(.*) (.*)/(.*)}) { print $1, $_ for $2 .. $3 }'
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` adds a newline to each `print`
- `m{}` is the matching operator
- `.` matches anything except a newline
- `*` means "zero or more times"
- parentheses create "capture groups"
- so, we match anything, space, anything, slash, anything; all the anythings being remembered in $1, $2, and $3 respectively
- `..` is the range operator

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) can you kindly explain how this command works? and what the .* does?

Comment: many thanks for your help it is very clear now :) since i have different range ex 12345 00/99 and 1234 000/999 is there a way for the shell to identify the range automatically?

Comment: @luuke: What do you mean? Did you get wrong output? Or is your input different?